# vscode shows jsdoc type name except full properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I have this typedef's**

```js
/**
 * DBH auth object
 * @typedef DBH_Auth
 * @property {String|null} login - user login
 * @property {String|null} email - user email
 * @property {String} password - user password
 */

/**
 * DBH jwt string
 * @typedef {String} DBH_JWT
 */
```

Using it in this method

```js
/**
 * @param {Object} opts
 * @param {DBH_JWT} opts.jwt
 * @param {DBH_Auth} opts.auth
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
updateUser(opts) {
    //...
}
```

And VSCode shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0ovS.png).

I want VSCode show `DBH_Auth` propeties except type name.

Comment: Have you considered using typescript?

Comment: Not considered, rewriting the entire project would be a difficult task.

Comment: So, you can do that by inlining `DBH_Auth` definition into function definition (as `@param opts.auth.email`) but that may be hard if you have a lot of functions or going to change typedef later